# Umbraco 7: How can I refresh the tree view in my custom section?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco7

I have created a custom section in umbraco to manage some data in an SQL database.

I can edit items OK but when adding I need to refresh the page to see my new row in the custom tree on the left.

How can I cause a refresh of my custom tree using AngularJS? My tree is called "clients".

I have tried debugging the code and looking at the source to find the event but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

Is there a method I can call on the `umbTreeDirective` somehow? Or an event to subscribe to?

I am fairly new to AngularJS and am struggling a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the  [navigationService](http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api/umbraco.services.navigationService).

This line is example of a syncTree call:

`navigationService.syncTree({ tree: 'clients', path: content.path, forceReload: false, activate: true });`

Here's a contrived, spaghetti promised but full example:

```
angular.module("umbraco")
.directive('nowplaying', ['navigationService', 'contentResource', 'contentEditingHelper', function (navigationService, contentResource, contentEditingHelper) {

                //spaghetti example to create new document
                contentResource.getScaffold(parentId, alias)
                .then(function (scaffold) {
                    var myDoc = scaffold;
                    myDoc.name = name;

                    //we have minimum to publish
                    contentResource.publish(myDoc, true, [''])
                        .then(function (content) { 
                            $scope.newlyCreatedNode = content;  

                                //Sync ('refresh') the tree!
                                navigationService.syncTree({ tree: 'clients', path: content.path, forceReload: false, activate: true });

                    });
                });
}]);
```

All of the [Belle documentation lives here](http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api). -I'm not sure it's actively maintained, i can say for certain that one or two signatures have changed since it was first posted. That aside, it's the best resource i know of to interact with all the umbraco exposed modules and services.